# returning affected_rows causes error in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a function which is to `update` my database rows! I added another query to the beginning of this function which inserts new rows to the database. at the end of function I return `affected_rows()`, but when there is some new information to add to the database using `insert`, and nothing happens to the previous rows, it returns error!

```
function update()
{    
    $this->db->insert('products', $some_options);

    $this->db->set('product_Title', $options['product_Title']);

    $this->db->where('product_Id', $options['product_Id']);

    $this->db->update('products');

    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

In my controller I have :

```
if($this->products_model->update($_POST))
{
    echo 'changed succuessfully';
}
else
{
    'sorry, nothing changed';
}
```

Of course, I want to know whether database rows are changed or not(including new information which are added to the database) and show a message to user! What can I do?!

Comment: I changed my question. have a look at it

Comment: it's probably because your $this->db->update is failing. try debugging using echo $this->db->last_query();exit(); after the update statement. you will get the SQL using this.